# Why is SIGFPE not triggered after adding a printf line?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am playing with a simple program (source code below). And my computer configuration:

Linux mymachine 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void catcher(int a){
  setresuid(geteuid(),geteuid(),geteuid());
  printf("WIN!\n");
  system("/bin/sh");
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  puts("source code is available in level02.c\n");

  if (argc != 3 || !atoi(argv[2]))
    //printf("!atoi(argv[2]) = %d\n", !atoi(argv[2]));
    return 1;
  signal(SIGFPE, catcher);
  printf("end\n");

  return abs(atoi(argv[1])) / atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

I intend to trigger the SIGFPE in this program by calling the executable in this way:

```
$./a.out -2147483648 -1
source code is available in level02.c

end
WIN!
```

As you can see, the SIGFPE is successfully triggered. However, if I uncomment a single printf line in the argument checking "if" condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void catcher(int a){
  setresuid(geteuid(),geteuid(),geteuid());
  printf("WIN!\n");
  system("/bin/sh");
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  puts("source code is available in level02.c\n");

  if (argc != 3 || !atoi(argv[2]))
    printf("!atoi(argv[2]) = %d\n", !atoi(argv[2]));
    return 1;
  signal(SIGFPE, catcher);
  printf("end\n");

  return abs(atoi(argv[1])) / atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

And then I recompile the program and try to trigger SIGFPE using the same way. I only get this:

```
source code is available in level02.c
```

What is happening?

Comment: i cannot remember where the code is from. In anyway, I dont think this question is asking about the solution. Let me know if otherwise and I can remove the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because now your source code is mis-indented compared to how it is actually parsed.

```
if (argc != 3 || !atoi(argv[2]))
    printf("!atoi(argv[2]) = %d\n", !atoi(argv[2]));
return 1;
```

Consider putting both statements in a block instead to avoid this.

Comment: Ooh...too much python programming lately...Thank you!